# Outgoing bandwidth includes EdgeCache hits?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, bandwidth

What is counted as "Outgoing Bandwidth" when running an GAE app?
Setting proper cache headers on responses from the server, the response should be cached and served from the "Google Global Cache", right?
What about content/responses served from this cache, are these also considered as Outgoing Bandwidth?

Answer (score -1):

Of course they will not count it as there are too many places where it could be cached, but it will work only for static items.

Comment: That would be great, but it corresponds to AWSs CloudFront, which is billed... Is "cdn" free at GCP?

Comment: Also, evidently, setting cache headers on resposes, makes requests get served from cache. So, not only for static items(?).